# Java FX code works on Windows, but not on Mac OS; How Do I Run JavaFX on Mac OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

I have a JavaFX program that works on Windows, but fails to work on Mac OS.

I have MacOS Sierra 64bit (latest as of March 11), 
JDK 8u121,
Eclipse IDE - NEON

Here is the behavior: On pressing "RUN", the coffee cup shows up in the dock, but everything freezes. I then have to force quit it.

Something important that I noticed: When I write a test app ( e.g a borderpane with a button) it works perfectly fine. However, there seems to been an issue in transferring code from windows

PS. I've read about this issue online, but all I have found, are answers for previous operating systems and jdks.

UPDATE:

Consider this:

```
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
public class testClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "SELECT", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My Observation: On Windows, A Dialog Box appears with SELECT as the title.

Upon running it on mac, a dialog box appears, but with NO title.

---

Now, consider this:

When I comment out FileDialog, the code works fine, it brings up a 500x500 window. 
However, when I include the FileDialog part, it gets stuck. (Not Responding)

```
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class testClass extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "LOAD", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);

        Group g = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(g, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Post code for a sample application that behaves this way.

Comment: There are always some subtle differences between operating systems but in general it is no problem transfering code between windows and the mac.

Comment: @mipa Interesting, Have you tried to the same? ( Transferring code from Windows to Mac)

Comment: Lots of people have tried it, you should try to come up with a [MCVE] that demonstrated the problem you're running into, describe your environment, details of invocation, jdk/jre versions you are using, etc.

Comment: @pvg, Im sorry if I am in the wrong forum, could you please direct me on the correct one? My code is not an issue here, since works perfectly fine on Windows.

Comment: The code does appear to be the issue though. As you've stated a test app worked fine - now try and make it as close to your actual app until the issue appears. Try to replicate the issue in a sample app to post here.

Comment: Right. I'll try that asap Matthew. Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is with the FileDialog. It doesnt work correctly on osx

Comment: @Matt_Raj I think you're probably in the right forum and the thing is not about code, it's about reproducibility. If it worked on windows and that in itself was fine, you wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: Pvg, what do you think about the problem, about filedialog

Answer (score 0):

You should be using JavaFX's FileChooser, not an AWT FileDialog. The AWT/Swing components and JavaFX are from different bloodlines and can not readily be intermixed. The fact that this runs on Windows is more a fluke than anything.

Comment: Thank You! This worked for me. However, I still have one question: How can I get the title to show? I did this: `fd.setTitle("Choose a File")`